# Search by properties of two Entities (fetch from two Entities)

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, core-data

Let's say I have two entities, `A` and `B`. My goal is to implement the search by all properties of `A` and just one property of `B`, and to display sum of search results in one `tableView`. Naturally I can set `fetchRequest` only by one entity. But if I am understand right I can fetch not only from `A` but from `B` too if they are connected with relationships.
So what do I need to do to implement this? Does default fetch fetches all properties from `A` and `B`? If not, how can I specify fetch of all properties from `A` and one property of `B` in one fetch?

Comment: Are your entities related, show them? Are you going to show a list of `A` as the results? Have you read about predicates?

Comment: Yes they are related with many-to-many relationships, set to inverse. I want to show list of results including searching from all of `A` properties and only one `property` of `B`. I think in my case predicate should be something like [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"relationship.property CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString]; I tried this but I am retrieving (null) as a result for this `property` of `B`. Looks like basic fetch from `A`fetches only from `A`, even if relationships is set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved.
At the stage of preloading data from `JSON` file into `Core Data` I am define getters for properties (prefetching data from entity)in `B` and setting entity properties of `A` equal to returned results of this getters (all this in NSManagedObject subclasses inherited from entities). So after that I am able to fetch all what I need using this getters through appropriate properties.